# Mismatch in Adsense click count

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

Since shifting to wordpress blog, I am noticing a huge mismatch in adsense click data. I used to get around 15 clicks on average. Nowadays also I see same amount of clicks. However, when I see report with "Ad Size" or "Custom Channel" as dimension, it shows only 2 or 3 clicks.

What is happening here? Any ideas?[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How are you handling your ads in WordPress?   Are you using the custom channels in WordPress?   It seems likely to me that the ads are just configured differently in WordPress.   This is causing the custom channel reporting to be less useful.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, i am using custom channels. one ad unit had two custom channels associated with it which probably caused duplicate counting.